# Best VNC / remote desktop software for assistance

Tags: software-recommendation, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-assistance

Poll on best VNC / remote desktop software for assisting others on Windows/Mac machines from Ubuntu?

I've heard good things about TeamViewer and Fog Creek Copilot, but I'm wondering if the included GNOME Vinaigre VNC client is good enough for this.

To specify, I'm looking for best option based on:

1. ***SIMPLEST*** ease-of-use for client to download/use on their end.
2. See #1.
3. Works cross-platform
4. I am able to control client's mouse and/or keyboard from remote machine.

Comment: Technically, VNC is only one kind of desktop sharing software. Both TeamViewer and Copilot use proprietary, non-VNC connection methods.

Comment: interesting note, did not know there are other types.

Comment: Voting to leave open as ALL software-recommendation questions that have more than one answer are primarily opinion based. Asking for a recommendation is in effect asking for an opinion. If we don't allow this we should eliminate the tag.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software lists many products, and provides a matrix of features for each major OS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're planning on providing assistance to someone who is not very computer savvy, **TeamViewer** is going to make your life far easier. Yes, it is a closed-source commercial product – but the magical sensation you feel when establishing a connection using only an ID number makes it all well worth it.

For a while you might think you can pull off carefully setting up a VNC server and the required firewall/NAT rules to be ready for future support sessions, but it won't do you any good the day that your friend in need of assistance has changed their network setup or broken their server configuration by following some Hoary Hedgehog how-to.

It's pretty hard to get this part wrong:

[image: TeamViewer]

With most of my clients, I don't even have them try to install TeamViewer. Session initiation looks like this:

1. At [teamviewer.com/download](http://www.teamviewer.com/download/), click the button beneath "TeamViewer **QuickSupport**".
2. Click Run.
3. Read me the ID and password.

Comment: I fully agree. This is one of the very seldom cases, where I also suggest a closed source product over all the free and open source alternatives, just because it is much easier for the inexperienced user at the other end.

Comment: Sounds like this is the winner.

Comment: Appreciated the practical choice answer

Comment: This is impressive - because it's _very_ easy to use, nearly nothing to configure, and it just works! I just tested a connection from iPhone to Ubuntu - totally straightforward.

Answer (score 8):

[Remmina](https://remmina.org/) is pretty easy to set up and use. Highly recommended for novice and expert alike. Install it with:

```
sudo apt install remmina
```

Comment: Could you provide (or link to) some basic instructions on how to configure it? There is some rudimentary info in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145537/how-to-configure-remmina-for-vnc-desktop-sharing), but I would hope for something more descriptive...

Answer (score 7):

#### [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp)

Yet another solution is **[Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp)**.

After [installing](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp), access it from Chromium home page or click at "Launch the App" at [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp).

[image: screenshot]

Your friend will have to click at "Share Now":

[image: screenshot]

And give you the code:

[image: screenshot]

**Advantages**:

- Doesn't require Wine (~190MB to download and ~500MB of space in disk, and security issues).
- Super easy to install and no configuration is needed.
- Fast connection.

---

Another great solution is **[Mikogo](http://www.mikogo.com/download/linux-download/)** (which doesn't use Wine). Download, extract, run and share (no installation required):

[image: screenshot]

Mikogo is just as easy to set-up and use as TeamViewer (and is also cross-platform, closed-source, commercial but free for private use). Once you `Start a session` it is only a matter of communicating to the other user the 9-digit session ID. The other user would then `Join session` using this ID. See a review [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/mikogo-cross-platform-desktop-sharing.html).

Answer (score 4):

I am fairly sure the default one included in Ubuntu will work with another one on Windows/Mac. Check for some of them on this page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vnc

Remember on Ubuntu to set up a machine to be able to be controlled, you have to go to: System -> Preferences -> Remote Desktop. Set a strong password. You can view other machines without doing this though.

Comment: Thanks Nightwish, I will check this out. I would *prefer* to be using a ubuntu tool, but will have to depend on if it works. =)

Comment: How do you access `Remote Desktop` on Xubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

For Windows UltraVNC is fairly simple for the end user.  Its a pain to set up initially as you have to open ports for the server but it's open source and free.  Once the server is set up and the client file is set up its simple enough.
http://www.uvnc.com/pchelpware/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to an excellent( & credible) article which contains reviews of some remote-desktop clients for linux, "Remmina" is judged as the best:
[7 of the best Linux remote desktop clients](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/7-of-the-best-linux-remote-desktop-clients-716346)

Comment: Thanks jumbli, I will check this out. Comparison is good!

Answer (score 1):

---

MeshCentral (and Remotely) seems good alternatives. Much more Jami.

**Note**: * means FOSS.

### P2P

- **Jami**<sup>*</sup> ([install](https://jami.net/download-jami-linux/#open-modal-ubuntu-22.04)) - Open Source, Peer-to-Peer, Audio, Video, Conferencing, Chat, and Screen Sharing System. [Here](https://youtu.be/2Wi99K33qrw) a video describing it.

#### Using a repeater service/gateway (for firewalled/NATed hosts, both sides)

Using a middleware proprietary gateway: No need to connect directly to an IP+port.

- [chrome remote desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/): Supporting to Windows client doesn't show the full-screen-grayed admin confirmation dialogs. 5'-valid code: not unattended.
- [dwservice.net](https://www.dwservice.net/)
- [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/)
- [AnyDesktop](https://anydesk.com/en/downloads): I'm getting [`desk_rt_ipc_error` error](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/anydesk-error-desk-rt-ipc-error-alternative-working-remote-desktop/111487/4)
- [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/)
- [LogMeIn](https://www.logmein.com/)
- [Remotely](https://remotely.one/)<sup>*</sup>: ([source](https://github.com/immense/Remotely/)).
- [**MeshCentral**](https://meshcentral.com/)<sup>*</sup> ([source](https://github.com/Ylianst/MeshCentral)).
- [**rustdesk**](https://rustdesk.com/))<sup>*</sup> ([source](https://github.com/rustdesk/rustdesk/)). *The open source alternative to TeamViewer. RustDesk is a full-featured open source remote control alternative for self-hosting and security with minimal configuration.* But uses ports 21115-21119 and no plans to use standards ports like 443.
- [Nextcloud Talk](https://nextcloud.com/talk/)

#### Client or server port directly accessible<sup>*</sup>

Without firewall/NAT (on a LAN/forwarding ports/or NAT passthrough/Listening mode):

- [VNC (RFB)/RDP/SPICE/NX (proprietary) clients](https://www.techradar.com/best/best-linux-remote-desktop-clients)

  - [TigerVNC](https://tigervnc.org/)
  - [Remmina](https://remmina.org/) (VNC&RDP[+SSH])
  - [GNOME Vinagre](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Vinagre/)
  - [Vino](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vino): GNOME desktop sharing server.
- [Veyon](https://veyon.io/) Classroom-oriented
- [Guacamole](https://guacamole.apache.org/): Different: web-based client, you need to install the server somewhere

---

- **Related projects<sup>*</sup>**

  - [sslh](https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh): Application Protocol Multiplexer (e.g. share SSH and HTTPS on the same port)
  - [sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle): poor man's VPN: Just `sshuttle --dns -r username@sshserver:port 0.0.0.0/0`, for all networks/hosts.
  - [corkscrew](https://github.com/bryanpkc/corkscrew/): Tunneling SSH through HTTP proxies
  - [Outline](https://getoutline.org/) (Shadowsocks based): OpenVPN easier alternative
  - [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) (WebRTC): Sharing screen (read only and not unattended), more like [Zoom](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360020436071-Security-CVE-2018-15715). [Related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1389650/349837).
  - To [share just terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32498909/4970442): [tmate](https://tmate.io/) or [GoTTY](https://github.com/yudai/gotty)
- **Related links**

  - [Comparison of remote desktop software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software)
  - [An Intro to WebRTC’s NAT/Firewall Problem](https://webrtchacks.com/an-intro-to-webrtcs-natfirewall-problem/)
  - [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) *One command for an instant, secure URL to your localhost server through any NAT or firewall.*