# How to configure Remmina for VNC desktop sharing?

Tags: 12.04, vnc, remmina

I'm trying to connect two PCs for desktop sharing, I was able to set up ssh shell and file sharing but I failed to connect to VNC server.

There are additional packages that I need to install on my machines?

And how should I fill this dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

To use VNC, you must have a VNC server installed and running on the machine.

```
sudo aptitude install vnc4server
```

Follow the instructions

```
You will require a password to access your desktops.

Password:
Verify:
Password too long - only the first 8 characters will be used
xauth:  creating new authority file /home/server/.Xauthority

New 'server:1 (root)' desktop is server:1

Creating default startup script /home/server/.vnc/xstartup
Starting applications specified in /home/server/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/media/.vnc/media:1.log
```

Now you can connect to this machine using Remmina on the other machine.

Reference: [Install VNC Server and VNC Client on Ubuntu](http://bookofzeus.com/articles/linux/install-vnc-server-and-vnc-client-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: If I leave this machine on login screen, can I then connect to it?

Comment: Yes, as long as the server is running, you should be able to login.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. It would connect to a remote server but the screen remained blank. Possibly the version installed with the distribution has a problem. I removed it and then installed the latest version from the Remmina website https://www.remmina.org/wp/. This version works OK for ssh for me.

For Ubuntu users we have an official [PPA with Remmina 1.2](https://launchpad.net/~remmina-ppa-team/+archive/ubuntu/remmina-next)

To install it, just copy and paste the following three lines on a terminal window

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-gnome libfreerdp-plugins-standard
```

ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next supports all currently supported versions of Ubuntu (14.04, 16.04, 17.04, 17.10, 18.04).

Answer (score 2):

For which protocol you wish to configure it?

For **VNC** or **RDP** or other it is very simple.

If you are going for the `ABC` user remote control then give that name in **Name tab**

Then choose protocol.

then put **IP address** of remote machine in **Server Tab**. Then press **connect**

If you already know **Username/Password** then you can fill it in appropriate tabs.

But first you need to enable/install **VNC/RDP** on the related machine.

for that go to **Desktop Sharing** and enable it.

Comment: I'm interested in VNC protocol, think it was quite explained in the question..

Comment: How can enable/install VNC/RDP on the related machine ?

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Typing 'users' in the Mac terminal gave me my username.

Comment: How do you access `Desktop Sharing` on Xubuntu? I can't find it anywhere in the menus...