# Ubuntu Remote Contol

Tags: 14.04

I want to install Ubuntu on someone's computer across town. But I want full control of this machine from my home Computer. I want to be able to work on if from home and take control of it from home.

How can I do this?

Comment: VNC, Remmina, rDesktop. See for instance https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/remmina/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/145537/how-to-configure-remmina-for-vnc-desktop-sharing

Answer (score 0):

The most easy to deploy and use tool is TeamViewer (which is crossplatfrom). You don't need to register, bring up tunnels or anything else (of course if you don't have restrictions in your home network). You just should have running TeamViewer on another computer and have automatically-generated number and password of remote machine.

The other ways is to bring up VNC server on remote machine, but you should make VNC ports forwarded to machine's public address or bring DDNS on remote router (and forward ports too), which one way is harder then first.

There is also RDP protocol realisation on Linux (Ubuntu as well), way to make it works same as VNC.

And of course CLI access done by ssh. Bring up SSH server on remote computer, forward it's port to public address and do your best, you can't access desktop in that case, but can run X11 applications of remote computer via SSH, see SSH X11 forwarding for that case.

Comment: Just install this tool on your and remote desktop. It's also allows you to control any other system remotely like Windows, MacOS, Unix where teamviewer running

Comment: this thing available even for Android, but not for Android remote control, you can control desktop from Android device

Comment: @SMcAbee if this answer helpfull for you please upvote it and accept as correct answer.