# setup Remmina for remote desktop connection

Tags: remmina

I have two computers running Ubuntu and have Remmina installed. I want 'How to' to setup both computer so that one computer can take remote desktop of other.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to be able to use Remmina, you need first to activate certain options of the "Desktop Sharing" screen (Dash -> Desktop Sharing) on both computers:

[image]

On the Desktop Sharing Preferences:

- Activate the option "Allow other users to view your desktop"
- Activate the option "Allow other users to control your desktop"

For security's sake, also:

- Activate the option "You must confirm each access to this machine"
- Activate the option "Require the user to enter this password" and provide a password

Once the configuration is done, you can simply open Remmina, create a new connection and specify the connection to the other computer using VNC  (virtual network computing) protocol and using the password you used in the "Desktop Sharing" screen. Hint: You can ignore the field "user".

Regards

Comment: what if I just want to use remmina, is it not possible?

Comment: I guess you could, the question is why would you do that if there's a much simpler way to control desktop between 2 Ubuntu devices. Is it a must? If so, you can have a look at this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145537/how-to-configure-remmina-for-vnc-desktop-sharing

Comment: Oh sorry, I just realized the Desktop Sharing feature precisely activates the VNC configuration needed to afterwards connect to the PC through like a client like... Remmina :-) I'll udpate the answer.

Comment: what do you mean `Bash > Desktop Sharing`?  I'm just using terminal.

Comment: @YanKingYin "Dash" :-)

Comment: and how can we access "Dash" from AwesomeWM?

Comment: @Paulo Silva I'm unfamiliar with that specific window manager, but launching it from the command line with "vino-preferences" might work.

Comment: how to perform those steps via ssh ?

Comment: these steps do not work conecting 20.04 dwsktop to 22.04