# Remmina VNC doesn't connect to remote machine

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote, remmina

I need to connect to a workstation from a personal machine but don't have any luck with it. The workstation is also Ubuntu 14.04.

My personal machine: Remmina 0.9.99.1, Ubuntu 14.04.

The window I get stuck with is saying it's trying to connect.

Help, please?

EDIT: Trying to access a remote machine via remote desktop. I can ssh to it with no problem.

The [rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gtq8.png) of the [config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVy1t.png).

Comment: What kind of connection are you trying to achieve? Simple ssh console access? Remote Desktop?... It seems to me you are selecting the wrong protocol, but just to bee sure tell exactly what you want to to and paste your remmina config, please

Comment: I can ssh to it with no problem, but what I'd really like to do is use the workstation as a remote desktop. I'm using the VNP - Virtual Network Computing protocol.  Please see the rest of the config in the original post!

Comment: Does it work without the ssh tunneling?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Gets stuck saying "Connecting to 'Oat toy'..." :(

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post and double check the configuration of the remote system allows vnc connections:

[setup Remmina for remote desktop connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698669/setup-remmina-for-remote-desktop-connection/698686#698686)

> In order to be able to use Remmina, you need first to activate certain
>   options of the "Desktop Sharing" screen (Bash -> Desktop Sharing) on
>   both computers:
>
> On the Desktop Sharing Preferences:
>
> - Activate the option "Allow other users to view your desktop"
> - Activate
>     the option "Allow other users to control your desktop"

Only activate the following if you are not trying to configure unattended access:

> For security's sake, also:
>
> - Activate the option "You must confirm each access to this machine"
> - Activate the option "Require the user to enter this password" and
>     provide a password
>
> Once the configuration is done, you can simply open
>   Remmina, create a new connection and specify the connection to the
>   other computer using VNC (virtual network computing) protocol and
>   using the password you used in the "Desktop Sharing" screen.
>
> Hint: You can ignore the field "user".

Try it first without SSH and, if it works, then start playing with tunneling.

Comment: That's what I did initially with no luck. Having to do X forwarding when using ssh now.

Comment: I think you mean Dash -> Desktop Sharing (rather than Bash) :)