# remmina - Can't use SSH

Tags: ssh, 17.10, remmina

On a freshly installed Ubuntu 17.10, I can use `ssh` on remote servers using terminal. But I can't with Remmina.

I get a black screen with a little white square (flashing or not). I also tried to use UTF-8 in preferences character.

Here is what I get in command lines :

```
me@myubuntu:~$ /usr/bin/remmina 
Remmina plugin RDP (type=Protocol) registered.
Remmina plugin RDPF (type=File) registered.
Remmina plugin RDPS (type=Preference) registered.
Remmina plugin VNC (type=Protocol) registered.
Remmina plugin VNCI (type=Protocol) registered.
Remmina plugin SFTP (type=Protocol) registered.
Remmina plugin SSH (type=Protocol) registered.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

(remmina:22188): Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to GtkScrollbar 0x55700821c610 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
```

Maybe you advise to use other software than Remmina? My need is to have a servers list as I did with MRemoteNG on Windows.

> How possibly five people say it is a duplicate of VNC problem?! I
>   never spoke about VNC but only SSH. First thing you can see in this
>   other problem, the person tells everything is fine for him with SSH,
>   the exact opposite of me!
>   I answer to myself... uninstall the Remmina version coming from
>   official Ubuntu and run sudo apt-add-repository
>   ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get
>   install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-gnome
>   libfreerdp-plugins-standard

Comment: Make sure you enter everything correctly in Remmina.

Comment: Hum, hard to say what is happening, can you try to open `remmina` from the terminal and look for an eventual output that may help us to find the issue?

Comment: Are you using the standard ports? I've had it work oddly with nonstandard ports.

Comment: I try to connect on port 22.

Comment: I answer to myself... uninstall the Remmina version coming from official Ubuntu and run sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-gnome libfreerdp-plugins-standard  (feel free to correct my english as usual...)

Comment: @nutopia Sorry, I can't vote to reopen this question because your solution is a duplicate of this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145537/how-to-configure-remmina-for-vnc-desktop-sharing/979408#979408 in the linked duplicate question.