# Live screencast with Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, screencast, desktop-recording

It's extremely necessary for me to screencast my desktop and work to some friends (with different computers).

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop. I searched many times, but I couldn't find any service or software that will support "live" desktop streaming on Linux.

What are my options, actually?

Comment: It's not clear if you want [desktop recorder (to a video)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-can-i-record-my-screen/95103) or a [remote desktop for support](https://askubuntu.com/q/4467/349837)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Teamviewer before. It's a free tool

https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/

They offer a .deb file as setup

The only condition here is, the other end too needs one. Teamviewer has a lite version which people on other end can use.